# What is this powder served with fried dango?

Tags: japanese-cuisine

While in Japan, my husband got some dango from a street vendor. It was dipped in some kind of sesame-based sauce, and served with a little powder to dip it in on the side:

[image: Picture of the dango]

What is that powder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are all kinds of powders served with dango to give them different flavors.  The image you have included looks like kinako (roasted soybean flour) which is traditional, but it could also be peanut butter powder which is a more modern addition to dango.

Comment: It did not taste like peanut butter, so it's probably Kinako then